# Optimize SQL query with aggregate function and case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I wonder if there is a more better way to write this SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderTotals( [OrderID] uniqueIdentifier NULL, OrderTotal money 
NULL) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_OrderTotals ON #OrderTotals(OrderID)

 Insert #OrderTotals (OrderID, OrderTotal)
    SELECT  o.Id,
    (CASE when o.OrderStatusId in (5,6,7) then  
    SUM(ISNULL(oi.[Price],0)* 
    ISNULL(oi.[InvoicedQty] ,0)+ ISNULL(oi.[TotalTax] ,0)) 

    When o.OrderStatusId not in (5,6,7) then
    SUM(ISNULL(oi.[Price],0)*(ISNULL(oi.[Quantity] ,0)
    - ISNULL(oi.[DeniedQuantity] ,0)) + ISNULL(oi. 
    [TotalTax] ,0)) end) as OrderTotal

    FROM orderItem oi
    inner join [Order] o on o.Id = oi.orderId
    WHERE  (o.Code = 'abc')
    group by o.id, o.OrderStatusId
```

I am getting performance hit by CASE I think, Its making query slow. I need this logic here just wonder if there is a better more efficient way to write it.

Here is my execution plan
[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: So there is a lot of data like about 100K+. Some of the fields have NULLs so thats why checking with ISNULL is there.

Comment: You want a clustered index.  Your table is going to be extremely inefficient without it in SQL 2008, as I recall.  Without it I believe the server doesn't have a good way to order the data on the disk, even temporarily.  But that's just my recollection.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write the query more like this:

```
select o.Id,
       (case when o.OrderStatusId in (5, 6, 7)
             then sum(coalesce(oi.Price * oi.InvoicedQty, 0) +
                      coalesce(oi.TotalTax, 0)
                     ) 
             else sum(coalesce(oi.Price * (oi.Quantity - coalesce(oi.DeniedQuantity, 0)), 0) +
                      coalesce(oi.TotalTax, 0)
                     ) 
        end)
from [Order] o join
     orderItem oi
     on o.Id = oi.orderId
where o.Code = 'abc'
group by o.id, o.OrderStatusId;
```

I think it still has too many `coalesce()` calls, but you don't provide enough information about  your data.

To optimize this, you want indexes on `Order(Code, orderId)` and `OrderItem(orderId)`;

Comment: hmm r u suggesting coalesce()is faster than ISNULL()

Comment: Yes index did make some difference but not too much.

Comment: Perhaps you just have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

case when should be part of SUM like.; ( SUM(case when .....) ),

```
Insert #OrderTotals (OrderID, OrderTotal)
    SELECT  o.Id,
    SUM(
    CASE when o.OrderStatusId in (5,6,7) 
    then  
    ISNULL(oi.[Price]* oi.[InvoicedQty] ,0) + ISNULL(oi.[TotalTax] ,0)
ELSE
    ( ISNULL(oi.[Price] * oi.[Quantity] ,0) - ISNULL(oi.[DeniedQuantity] ,0) ) + ISNULL(oi.[TotalTax] ,0) 

     END) 
  as OrderTotal
FROM orderItem oi
    inner join [Order] o on o.Id = oi.orderId
    WHERE  (o.Code = 'abc')
    group by o.id, o.OrderStatusId
```